# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nlsxbe in java.library.path

Tags: java, lotus-notes, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I had try to upgrade my lotus notes from 8.5 to 9. But my email agent(Java 1.7 with calling Notes.jar) has an error present:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nlsxbe in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.notes.NotesThread.load(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.notes.NotesThread.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.asl.mail.LotusMailer.sendMail(LotusMailer.java:67)
        at org.gov.doj.batch.Mail.main(Mail.java:80)
```

But when I uninstall the notes 9 and re-install notes 8.5, the email agent is work.

I had try to search some solution:

1. The classpath of notes is correct? Yes
2. try to add -Djava.library.path=%BATCH_DLLPATH%, but another error display:

   > java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files
   >   (x86)\IBM\Notes\nlsxbe.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

What is the problem? Does any other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem here isn't that the JVM can't find nlsxbe.dll.  It is that nlsxbe.dll can't find the DLL files that it depends on. Is C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\ on your computer's PATH?

Comment: Thanks Richard. Yes, %BATCH_DLLPATH% is "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes". But I think it is no need to use -Djava.library.path as the notes 9 had been installed successful and I can use the notes to send and receive email! So, is there any compatible problem for java library Notes.jar with Notes 9?

Comment: I didn't ask about the BATCH_DLLPATH or the java.library.path. I am asking about the PATH environment variable.

Comment: maybe this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21201491

Answer (score -1):

Since you have access to the Notes client, use the JRE that is packaged with the client to execute your Java code - `C:\Notes\jvm`.  This fixed this exact same problem for me with Notes V9.  Looks like the DLLs that are needed are in there.